# How can I ensure docker builds in parallel Jenkins builds do not conflict?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Docker Pipeline Plugin to have each Jenkins job run in a container. Each of my Jenkins jobs will run a `docker-compose build`. If I run many concurrent jobs, the `docker-compose` commands may conflict with each other. I understand that I could have each build use some unique string as the name for the docker network, or as the name/tag for the `docker-compose build` command, but I am hoping for a solution that does not require this. Perhaps there is a way to "namespace" each Jenkins Job container such that none of their resources can be shared?

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a custom [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) (for example commit id and/or job number) so the resources created by the compose file are unique and guessable. This way you don't need to modify the compose file itself not move it to another location.

`docker-compose` will recognize either the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable or you could pass it as an argument, for example  `docker-compose -p ${MY_UNIQUE_ID} build`.